# virtualenv with new Python and old set of packages

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, upgrade

I have my environment setup on `CentOS 6`, comes with default `Python 2.6.6`, and the `Django` version in production is 1.4.1

Recently, started working on porting the app to latest Long Term Support `Django 1.8`. Locally I have refactored the app to make it ready. Issue arose when pushed the changes to production, setup a `vituralenv` with Django 1.8, on basic test importing django gave exception. The underlying cause is straightforward i.e. Django 1.8 at minimum sports Python 2.7

The question is I need to setup a `virtualenv` with `Python 2.7.*` and Django 1.8, on the same host where `Python 2.6.6` is in use as a production environment Python interpreter, such that the new venv (with `Python 2.7.*` and `Django 1.8`) contains all the currently installed Python packages (I have lot lot of them).

Comment: You can use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in your existing environment. After creating a new **virtualenv** for `Pytnon 2.7.*` and `Django 1.8` use this requirements.txt like `pip install -r requirements.txt` within your new **virtualenv**

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I have added it in the answer now. I just shared my clumsy step in a hurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best possible way I have found:

1. Install `python 2.7.*`.
2. Use this newly installed python for `virtualenv`.
3. Copy the `site-packages` from python 2.6.6

---

New Python 2.7.8 - Create a new dir for fresh Python installtion

```
$ cd /var/www/myproject
$ mkdir new_py
$ cd /var/www/  or   cd ..
```

Donwload, untar, and install Python 2.7.8

```
$ wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.8/Python-2.7.8.tgz
$ tar -zxvf Python-2.7.8.tar.gz
$ cd Python-2.7.8
$ ./configure --prefix=/var/www/myproject/new_py/Python-2.7.8/
$ make && make install
```

Creating new `venv` in project direcroty i.e. `myproject` (replace it with your own project name) with newly installed Python 2.7.8 - specified with `-p` flag

```
$ virtualenv -p /var/www/myproject/new_py/Python-2.7.8/bin/python2.7 venv_djangoupgrade
New python executable in venv_py2.7.8/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in venv_py2.7.8/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

Copy the installed Python packages - (Or, the technical way is to get the list of installed packages `$ pip freeze > requirements.txt` , and once the `venv` is activated execute `$ pip install -r requirements.txt` it'll install the list of packages)

```
$ cp -R /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/* var/www/myproject/venv_djangoupgrade/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

For debian i.e. Ubuntu

```
$ cp -R /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/* /var/www/myproject/venv_py2.7_django1.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Activate the `venv`

```
$ source djangoupgrade_venv/bin/activate
(djangoupgrade_venv) $
```

In case you just didn't copy the `site-packages` but the pip freeze list, execute the following pip command while the venv is active

`(djangoupgrade_venv) $ pip install -r requirements.txt`

and finally install/upgrade Django

```
(djangoupgrade_venv) $ pip install -U django==1.8
```

---

Execute the above commands as `root` or use `sudo`

Comment: It is **not** recommended to copy `site-packages` from another Python version. Installed packages may be Python version specific and lead to hard to debug issues. Instead to copy a virtualenv one should use `pip freeze` command as suggested in the comments above.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I use pip freeze before moving, but just this time I didn't run pip install - requirements to make it quick. I have added it in the answer .